# How can I do element-wise arithmetic on Numpy matrices?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using Numpy's `matlib` style matrices for a particular algorithm. This means that the multiplication operator `*` performs the equivalent of an `ndarray`'s `dot()`:

```
>>> import numpy.matlib as nm
>>> a = nm.asmatrix([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
>>> b = nm.asmatrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
>>> a * b
matrix([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]])
```

Is there a method to perform element-wise arithmetic, like the `*` operator does on `ndarray`s?

Comment: There is a more or less well established consensus among numpy developers that everyone would be better off if `np.matrix` didn't exist, or at least no one used it. If you can make your code work with `np.array` and `np.dot`, do it: it will probably spare you many headaches.

Comment: @Jaime Yes, I can see why — there are far too many weird surprises. It's just a shame there's no conjugate-transpose operator for `ndarray`s (ie. like MATLAB's `'`). It makes this particular code, which is quite compact in MATLAB, unbelievably verbose in Python.

Comment: @detly for a `ndarray` you can do `.T`...

Comment: There was some discussion about that on the numpy-dev mailing list. If I remember correctly, the non-consensus decission was that, while `a.T` returns a view and is therefore fast, `a.H` would have to run an ufunc on the array, and could be slow, so it should be a method, not an attribute, hence you are stuck with `a.T.conjugate()`.

Comment: On the bright side, since [PEP465](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pep%20465) got approved, in the first release of numpy that supports Python 3.5 (I'm guessing 1.11), you will be able to do `a @ b` for matrix multiplication and the usual `a * b` for Hadamard/Schurr/elementwise multiplication of ndarrays. But you will still be without a `.H` method, I'm afraid...

Comment: @SaulloCastro That is just transpose, not conjugate-transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.multiply`:

```
>>> a = np.matrix(np.random.rand(3,3))
>>> b = np.matrix(np.random.rand(3,3))
>>> a * b
matrix([[ 1.29029129,  0.53126365,  2.12109815],
        [ 0.99370991,  0.55737572,  1.9167072 ],
        [ 0.76268194,  0.43509462,  1.48640178]])
>>> np.asarray(a) * np.asarray(b)
array([[ 0.67445535,  0.12609799,  0.7051103 ],
       [ 0.00131878,  0.42079486,  0.5223201 ],
       [ 0.65558303,  0.03020335,  0.16753354]])
>>> np.multiply(a, b)
matrix([[ 0.67445535,  0.12609799,  0.7051103 ],
        [ 0.00131878,  0.42079486,  0.5223201 ],
        [ 0.65558303,  0.03020335,  0.16753354]])
```

It's a little unusual to want to perform elementwise multiplication on the same object you're performing matrix multiplication on, but you probably already know that. :^)  It might be worthwhile seeing if your algorithm has a nice `np.einsum` description, though.

Comment: It works! Much nicer than `np.asarray()` calls everywhere. And yes, most of the loops are almost definitely `einsum` candidates, but since I'm porting I want to get the reference code working, and then neaten it up.

Comment: You can abbreviate the `asarray` thing as `a.A * b.A`, although you no longer get a `np.matrix` then.